# useEffect re-renders more times than I would like

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

//Fetch method:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ data: null });
  useEffect(() => {
    setState((state) => ({ data: state.data }));
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setState({ data: json });
      });
  }, [url]);

  return state;
};


//My actual code:

function AdminDashboard() {
  const { data } = useFetch(
    //GET data

    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
  );
  console.log(data)
```

The console prints my data 3 times. The first and second it prints null, then it prints the actual data.

Comment: I think you could get it to two `console.log`s by removing the `setState` in `useEffect` because that's not needed. That's causing one `null` log message. Two logs are OK as the first is the initial render and the second will run once you've fetched the data.

Comment: You can have a look at the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-bogdan-ehl1v).

Comment: Your `console.log` is not done inside the `useEffect`, so why do you conclude that `useEffect` is rendering 3 times ?

Comment: @AWolf thank you for the clarification. It was confusing me why I was getting a null first because I thought the setState wouldn't be triggered before being called first in the fetch method.